# Preventing phpMyAdmin access from a limited set of IP's

Tags: linux, debian

How can I limit the access to phpMyAdmin from only specific IP addresses ? I want phpMyAdmin, which is hosted on a data center to be accessible only from the IP range in my office. LAMP and phpMyAdmin is running on a Debian 6 linux server.

Answer (score 1):

Add/Edit the following in your vhost configuration or in the corresponding `.htaccess` file:

```
<Location /path/to/phpmyadmin>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from 1.2.3.4
   Allow from 5.4.3.2
   Deny from all
</Location>
```

Replace the Path to the folder and the IP's as you need it.

Comment: Some more config info here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow